# Rake Task timing out on Heroku - Move Rake task to worker using Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sidekiq, worker

I recently realized that my rake tasks can time out on Heroku, and I happen to have...a lot of them.

Here is an example of my rake task:

```
namespace :test do

  desc "Test Rake Task"
  task get_list: :environment do
    require 'net/ftp'
    sftp = Net::SFTP.start('ftp.test.com','luigi', :password => 'pass_word')
    records = sftp.download!("luigi/list.xml")
    records_hash = Hash.from_xml(records)
    records_hash['Report']['Details'].each do |record|
      contact = Contact.create(              
          first_name: record['FirstName'],
          last_name: record['LastName'],
          date_of_birth: record['DateofBirth']
      )
      if contact.valid?
        puts "Created contact"
      else
        puts "Invalid contact"
      end
    end    
  end
end
```

I ***think*** that I need to move this to a background worker. It could take 5+ minutes to loop through this task and add each contact to the database. I would like to use `Sidekiq`, but I've never used "workers" or set this up before.

In general, how would I go about setting `Sidekiq` up to run on Heroku, and then move the above task to a background worker? I would like for this "worker" or "task" to be scheduled once a week, Monday mornings at 8 am.

My app settings:

```
Procfile:

web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

I am using a postgres Database, Rails 4.0.0, ruby 2.0.0, and as I mentioned earlier my app is hosted on Heroku.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Sidekiq docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki)? They are quite extensive, and include easy guides for getting started. The [Deployment page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment) even covers integration with Heroku. The [Getting Started page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started) will help you set up a Sidekiq worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the [Sidekiq documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki) and get it setup for Heroku.

One you have Sidekiq running, I recommend the following architecture:

- `ContactListWorker`: downloads list, enqueues a contact update job for each
- `ContactWorker`: given details, create/update a contact
- rake task `contacts:nightly_update` to queue up ContactListWorker job

Here's some rough pseudo code to show what that architecture might look like:

```
# rake contact:nightly_sync_list
namespace :contacts do
  desc "Test Rake Task"
  nightly_list_sync: :environment do
    ContactListWorker.perform_async
  end
end

class ContactListWorker
  require 'net/ftp'
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform()
    sftp = Net::SFTP.start('ftp.test.com','luigi', :password => 'pass_word')
    records = sftp.download!("luigi/list.xml")
    records_hash = Hash.from_xml(records)
    records_hash['Report']['Details'].each {|record| ContactWorker.perform_async(record) }
  end
end

class ContactWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(record)
    contact = Contact.create(
      first_name: record['FirstName'],
      last_name: record['LastName'],
      date_of_birth: record['DateofBirth']
    )
    if contact.valid?
      puts "Created contact"
    else
      puts "Invalid contact"
    end
 end
```

end

This architecture allows you to asynchronously kick off one background `ContactListWorker` job.  This job will do the download and quickly enqueue N `ContactWorker` jobs asynchronously.  This allows you to fan-out the processing across multiple Sidekiq workers and threads to distribute the processing.